# Arbitray link on pdf viewer sidebar

Tags: hyperref, pdf, koma-script, viewers

I'm using `KOMA-Script` with `hyperref`, and it wonderfully adds the table of contents in a navigable drop down tree on pdf viewers. I would like to add "arbitrary" lines in here. I would like to add links to the "Title Page" and "Contents" in the pdf side viewer side bar, but not in the ToC of the body of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I soon found the answer by reading the hyperref manual:

`\pdfbookmark[1]{Title}{LabelOfTitle}`